# Why does /etc/resolv.conf contain "search attlocal.net"?

Tags: networking, dns, resolv.conf

For Linux Mint 18.3

I began by reading several posts here and elsewhere about `/etc/resolv.conf`. Some of those posts reference -- but do not explain the function of -- a line of the form `search attlocal.net`.

I have also observed that IF I use a VPN to connect to the Internet, THEN the VPN software replaces the IP addresses of the DNS servers in */etc/resolv.conf* AND removes the line `search attlocal.net`. So it seems that `search attlocal.net` is not essential? Perhaps even "anti-useful" in some contexts?

So:

- What's the purpose of *search attlocal.net*?
- Is it desirable to configure whatever it is that populates */etc/resolv.conf* to NOT include *search attlocal.net* by default?
- Can, or should, *search attlocal.net* be replaced with something "better"? (And if yes, how?)

Comment: Have you tried `man resolv.conf` to see what information the manual pages provide? That's normally a good starting point if you wonder what should go in a standard configuration file.

Comment: I didn't try the man page simply because the thought didn't occur to me. It will occur to me going forward. I did, however, try lots of other searches. As stated, more or less regular references to search attlocal.net, no explanations. Thx...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `search` directive tells the DNS resolver to append the domain name to hostnames it can't find.

For example, if `/etc/resolv.conf` contains

```
server attlocal.net
```

And you do

```
ping somehost
```

the resolver will try to lookup an IP address for `somehost`. If that fails, it will try to lookup an IP address for `somehost.attlocal.net` before returning failure.

In your case, I'd guess it was set up via DHCP, as part of your initial, non-VPN connection, probably to an AT&T device (or clone). It's an attempt to make it easier for all the hosts served by the DHCP server to look like they have IP addresses in the same domain, and can use plain `hostname`s for each other.

When you activate your VPN, it wants ALL network traffic to go through the VPN. It doesn't want any traffic to go to `*.attlocal.net`. Since the VPN setup is rewriting `/etc/resolv.conf`, the `server` directive isn't needed